Fill a combox with the current value of my database
I have a situation: whenever I update a client on the application I'm trying to make, it simply captures the current value of the combobox to all the clients on my list. I'm working with a DataGridView, and the DataGrid prints the new value correct; however, the combobox doesn't.
Like said above, if I update a client, that combobox will keep the same value to all clients; it won't get the current value to each client in my database. And if I restart the application or simply if I don't update a client, it will get the SelectedIndex set for default, instead of the one related to the client. Here's how my current code works... Please help!!
// UPDATING METHOD, INSIDE CRUD CLASS

public void UpdateClient(int id_cliente, string[] rowsDB, string[] rowsForms)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            string updateQuery = "UPDATE cliente SET ";

            for (int i = 0; i < rowsDB.Length; i++)
            {
                updateQuery += $"{rowsBD[i]} = @{rowsBD[i]}";

                if (i < rowsDB.Length - 1)
                    updateQuery += ", ";
            }

            updateQuery += " WHERE id_cliente = @id_cliente";

            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(updateQuery, connection))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rowsDB.Length; i++)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{rowsDB[i]}", rowsForms[i]);
                }

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_cliente", id_cliente);

                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cliente atualizado com sucesso!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cliente não encontrado ou nenhum campo foi alterado.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o cliente: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

// FUNCTIONAL BUTTON 
private void Estados()
{
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("AC Acre");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("AL Alagoas");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("AP Amapá");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("AM Amazonas");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("BA Bahia");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("CE Ceará");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("DF Distrito Federal");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("ES Espírito Santo");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("GO Goiás");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("MA Maranhão");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("MT Mato Grosso");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("MS Mato Grosso do Sul");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("MG Minas Gerais");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("PA Pará");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("PB Paraíba");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("PR Paraná");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("PE Pernambuco");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("PI Piauí");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("RJ Rio de Janeiro");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("RN Rio Grande do Norte");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("RS Rio Grande do Sul");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("RO Rondônia");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("RR Roraima");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("SC Santa Catarina");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("SP São Paulo");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("SE Sergipe");
    cb_Estado.Items.Add("TO Tocantins");

    cb_Estado.SelectedIndex = 24;
}

private void SelectedClientAutoFill()
{
    if (dataGridView_Clientes.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView_Clientes.SelectedRows[0];

        // Preencha os campos do formulário com os dados do cliente selecionado
        tb_NomeCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
        tb_EmailCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Email"].Value.ToString();
        tb_TelefoneCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Telefone"].Value.ToString();
        tb_EnderecoCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Endereço"].Value.ToString();

        cb_TipoCliente.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells["Tipo de Cliente"].RowIndex.ToString();

        tb_CpfCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["CPF/CNPJ"].Value.ToString();
        tb_Numero.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Número"].Value.ToString();
        tb_BairroCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Bairro"].Value.ToString();
        tb_CidadeCliente.Text = selectedRow.Cells["Cidade"].Value.ToString();

        cb_Estado.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells["Estado"].RowIndex.ToString();
    }

    [...]

    private void UpdateDataGridView()
    {
        string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;username=root;password=;database=projeto_integrador";
        dataGridView_Clientes.Rows.Clear();

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM cliente";

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int idCliente = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id_cliente"]);
                string nome = reader["nome"].ToString();
                string email = reader["email"].ToString();
                string telefone = reader["telefone"].ToString();
                string endereco = reader["endereco"].ToString();
                string tipo_cliente = reader["tipo_cliente"].ToString();
                string cpf_cnpj = reader["cpf_cnpj"].ToString();
                int numero = Convert.ToInt32(reader["numero"]);
                string bairro = reader["bairro"].ToString();
                string cidade = reader["cidade"].ToString();
                string estado = reader["estado"].ToString();

                dataGridView_Clientes.Rows.Add(idCliente, nome, email, telefone, endereco, tipo_cliente, cpf_cnpj, numero, bairro, cidade, estado);
            }

            reader.Close();

            SelectedClientAutoFill();
        }
    }

    private void ib_Update_Client_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView_Clientes.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Obtém o ID do cliente selecionado
                int id_cliente =   Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView_Clientes.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value);

                // Verifica se algum campo foi alterado no formulário
                if (AlteredRows())
                {
                    // Defina os campos do banco de dados e do formulário que devem ser atualizados
                    string[] camposBD = { "nome", "email", "telefone", "endereco", "tipo_cliente", "cpf_cnpj", "numero", "bairro", "cidade", "estado" };
                    string[] camposForms = { tb_NomeCliente.Text, tb_EmailCliente.Text, tb_TelefoneCliente.Text, tb_EnderecoCliente.Text, cb_TipoCliente.SelectedItem.ToString(),    tb_CpfCliente.Text, tb_Numero.Text, tb_BairroCliente.Text, tb_CidadeCliente.Text, cb_Estado.SelectedItem.ToString() };

                    // Chama o método AlteraCliente com os dados do cliente
                    consulta.AlteraCliente(id_cliente, camposBD, camposForms);

                    // Atualiza o DataGridView após a alteração
                    
                    // Already tried bringing AlteredRows() here, but to no avail. (This function verifies if there's any altered info on my App's Forms, and seemingly works fine)
                    UpdateDataGridView();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nenhum campo foi alterado.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

First time using this, so again, I just want a solution to this issue. Not sure if it's the proper way to write the question... xD

I didn't fully understand the question; are you saying "I have 10 clients, when any one of them changes a combobox value, all the other 9 combo boxes on the other 9 computers should instantly also change to the same value" ?

Nah, in my app, I have a sign up form, and a DataGrid listing all the clients I have. I want to, when I click in one of my clients, all info about that client is automatically filled. Currently, the ComboBoxes of my forms (which are two), are showing the current value selected, instead of the value saved on my Database

So is it A) ... you have a grid showing some clients, and it has maybe some other columns showing values. You have downloaded a lot of data out of the database. Elsewhere on the form you have combo boxes and textboxes and date pickers etc which are intended to be used to edit the values associated with a client. You want to click a row in the grid and all the edit controls on the form will change to show the values from the row you clicked. You use the combos and textboxes etc to edit the values in the grid columns, rather than directly editing in the grid

Or is it B) ... and pi have a grid showing multiple different client names. When you click on a name you want the application to go to the database, pull all the data associated with that client and show it in combo boxes and textboxes etc elsewhere on the form, not in the grid. You will use the combo boxes etc to edit the data and save it back to the db. The application doesn't download a large amount of data out of the database, it only initially downloads enough to fill a few columns of the grid and then later will download more data but about a single client at a time

yes, it's actually kinda both cases... lol. I have a sign up form with like, 9 textboxes or so, and two ComboBoxes. When i click on a row, I want it to retrieve full information of my database, and I DO edit the info via the TextBoxes and ComboBoxes. However, as my code is now, it doesn't retrieve the info from the ComboBoxes correctly when I click in my DataGrid.

Perhaps it would help to show screenshots of your form in the question. I still didn't quite understand what you want to do, or what is going wrong.
